# Поиск элемента по дереву в iframe

Tags: javascript, html5

Нужно в iframe найти найти блок по классу и удалить его. Как это реализовать на чистом js?

Comment: Если iframe не с того же сайта, что и исходная страница, то никак.

Comment: на любом JS, независимо от степени ег очистоты, вам придется либо засовывать функцию поиска/удаления в страницу-источник фрейма, либо возиться с доступом к фрейму в пределах одного сайта (но если так, то вам скорее всего таки проще влезть прямо в код страницы), либо настраивать в браузере cross-origin policy (и работать это будет только у вас, ну и у тех, у кого такие же настройки).  Ибо это небезопасно - иначе любой школьник мог бы делать  фишинговые сайты, кладя в iframe, скажем, сайт платежной системы или интернет-магазина и скриптом подставляя собственные реквизиты для перевода денег.